# What is the probability distribution of $\int_{0}^{T}x^2(t)~\text{d}t$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

Assume that $x(t)$ is a white Gaussian process with PSD $\sigma^2$; as a result,
$$\mathbb{E}[x(t)x(t-\tau)]=\sigma^2\delta(\tau).$$
Define the random variable $X$ as 
$$X=\int_{0}^{T}x^2(t)~\text{d}t,$$
where $T\in\mathbb{R}^+$ is finite. What is the distribution of $X$?

P.S. I tried to treat the integral as Riemann summation, to have a summation  of Chi-squared random variables. However, as the variance of the normal random variable at each time instant is infinit, I didn't have a progress.

Comment: If you divide by $T$ you should get a Gaussian distribution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Sample_mean .The limit as $n\to\infty$ of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ where $X_i$ are standard normal variables is a gaussian random variable. I'm guessing it should work the same as with the integral. The limit of a reimann sum should show this.